# Connecting to remote redis on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I'm using rails on heroku. I have a VPS with redis on it.
 I don't want to use Heroku redis as it is quiet costly than what i have right now.So I tried the following method
1. Added `gem 'redis'` to Gemfile.
2. Added the following code to /config/initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => "MYSERVER", :port => 6739, :password => "MYPASS")
```

and pushed it to github. 
Still it gives me error

Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Please help.

Comment: Whats the point of using Redis if you using it across the network? Its like a race car with square tires.

Comment: @max Need it for grape-attack configuration. It's the only alternative i got. I can't use redis of heroku since it's costly ( I've already invested a lot ). Got any alternatives to grape-attack? I want to throttle my API

Comment: Nope, however I think you need to set `env['REDIS_URL']` to [get grape-attack to use the correct url](https://github.com/gottfrois/grape-attack).  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: grape-attack won't use your `$redis` global either. Not sure if you can set a password, you might have to look [at the redis adapter](https://github.com/gottfrois/grape-attack/blob/master/lib/grape/attack/adapters/redis.rb) and subclass or monkeypatch it.

Comment: Oh Yeah, I see. How can I change that URL? 
I'm not sure how to change the URL, can you please help me with that?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: but how can i tell grape-attack to use that?

Comment: Try reading the readme next time... https://github.com/gottfrois/grape-attack

Comment: Thanks. my bad. But you could be a bit polite tho :) Nevertheless, thanks for your time.